# NumberFormat removing comma ( , ) from value?

Tags: android, localization, decimal, number-formatting

I have this little crazy method that removes decimal places from string value.

```
private double getDoubleFromString(final String value) throws ParseException {
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    Number number = format.parse(value);
    return number.doubleValue();
}
```

It produces values with out comma ( **,** ) if local language is 'en' it working fine, in other languages that contains **,** in that strings it's returns value without comma.

Ex :

```
xx,x 
result is xxx.
74,5 --> 745 (problem facing in this format)
74.5 --> 74.5 (working fine it string has dot)
```

I do need the separator to be a dot or a point and a comma along with value string. Does anybody have a clue of how to accomplish this little feat?

Comment: Have you tried use a replace and replace all "," and "." with ""?

Comment: just replace all comas to dots before processing the string. Or use custom locale, not `Locale.getDefault()` because locale is the one who defines the decimal separator

Comment: @Antonio i tried to replace , with .  before NumberFomat still it's not working.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I have to support localization in number formats.. like if value is 74.5 it should be 74.5 / 74,5 in all the languages. here it's a value, not a more separate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private double getDoubleFromString(final String value) throws ParseException {
      String newvalue= value.replace(",",".");
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        Number number = format.parse(newvalue);
        return number.doubleValue();
    }
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
try {
            Log.e("RESULT_DATA",getDoubleFromString("88,5")+"");
            Log.e("RESULT_DATA",getDoubleFromString("79.5")+"");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
03-22 18:37:09.173 7103-7103/? E/RESULT_DATA: 88.5
03-22 18:37:09.174 7103-7103/? E/RESULT_DATA: 79.5
```

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy can u explain more about it because its working fine in my device i have tested than post as ans

Comment: Change your local language as France in your device and check.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy did you read this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429347/numberformat-removing-comma-from-value/49429549?noredirect=1#comment85860315_49429347

Comment: My intention is application should support in all the countries without failing. like if value is 74.5 it should be 74.5 / 74,5 in all the languages. here it's a value, not a more separate.

Answer (score 0):

`NumberFormat` has special method for this purpose

```
/**
 * Set whether or not grouping will be used in this format.
 *
 * @param newValue {@code true} if grouping is used;
 *                 {@code false} otherwise
 * @see #isGroupingUsed
 */
public void setGroupingUsed(boolean newValue) {
    groupingUsed = newValue;
}
```